# Hotel Room Booking module in Node js & Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I am trying to build a booking engine for hotel in Node js and Parse for database management. I want to know how will the concurrency issue be solved. For example rooms shown available to a user might get booked by another user, while the first user in process of booking. Will this be handled by Parse or do I need to cache the availability of rooms or something else? Please help me out with the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look into "cloud code before save after-save" to handle your stale_ui , concurrency issues